# How to debug asmx web service in VS2019 ? VS no longer stops on breakpoints in web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asmx, visual-studio-debugging

This may be a duplicate question, but no answers for VS2019 that I can find actually work.
I found myself needing to debug a web service ASMX for an older web application, but Visual Studio 2019 won't stop on breakpoints set in the asmx file anymore (it breaks in all other code behinds and even for javascript).  I believe a setting in VS was unset somehow & I have no idea how to turn it back on.

Comment: What does it say when you hover your mouse over the inactive breakpoint?

Comment: It's solid red when executing - it should be hit. I set the service to be the start page, but even after invoking directly, the point is never hit.

Comment: For kicks, I added another function (Helloworld) to the webservice, and, put a breakpoint on it. The debugger decided to work. Reason: Unknown (have not ruled out demonic possession, lol).

Comment: sound like your source and what your trying to debug is out of sync. Clean and rebuild

Comment: Hi,have you started the service as a new instance while debugging your web application?  As far as l know, you should run the service as a new instance while debugging so that you can hit the breakpoint in the service file. Besides, don't know if you made any settings changes, you can try to restore the settings(`Tools-->Import and Export Settings-->Reset all settings`).